# Can Xcode windows be "document" windows instead of "browser" windows?

Tags: xcode

*Is there any way, any hack, any plugin, anything that can force Xcode to stop shifting window contents and make it work like a 'document editor' instead of a 'web browser'?*

**Background (not a rant, just clarifying the 'want'):**

Back in the old days of MPW, CodeWarrior and ObjectMaster the editor windows of the IDE acted like documents (aka opening a document in MS Word or Pages) instead of shifting their contents like a browser (aka Safari, FireFox).  When you opened a document in the Finder, it opened into it's own document window in your editor (a-la BBEdit, TextWrangler).

Today Xcode seems to want you to have only 1 window open and Xcode wants you to surf your code.  It is a constant battle to keep a organized workspace of 5, 10 or more "documents" open across my 3 monitors or even the single MacBook Pro screen.  When opening an Xcode source code "document" from the Finder, Xcode seemly randomly decides to replace the contents of the browsers and I loose context of my workspace. Clicking on a new "document" in the "Project Navigator" changes the content of the "browser" instead of opening up a new "document" window.

Yes, there is the option-command-click to get a new browser window instead of changing the current browser context, but there is nothing that keeps that content tied to that window.

*What I am looking for is a way to reverse the Xcode editor metaphor and make "browser" an option and "document" the norm editing code. Ideally option-command-click would instead trigger browsing (which I would never use :-)*

Comment: Found out that this problem is further exacerbated when having multiple projects open. A given project browser window does not stay tied to the project showing in the project navigation to the left.  Hitting the "back" button "<" can easily show a file from a different currently opened project. Talk about an opportunity to accidentally perform erroneous edits!

Comment: It got a tad worse in Xcode 9. Now Xcode 9 will randomly collect your windows into a single window with a bunch of tabs either upon re-opening Xcode or just using Expose and showing the Mac desktop.  Xcode tabs are now rated as "virus" in my book.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any hack, but is tabbing not enough? On the first tab i mostly use as file browser and other tabs just coding in specific files.

[image]

There is also shortcut keys for jumping back and fort.

[image]

I hope I could help.

PS: create Tab: File-> new -> tab or just press CMD+T

Comment: Tabbing is handy for working in a 13" screen but all the spatial organization is lost.  In meat-space for example, I have my work bench setup "just so" with the soldering iron on the upper right, the sponge just below and slightly to the left, the power supply for my PCB board connection to the upper left, my precision tools in the left hand drawer so while I hold the soldering iron with my right hand, I can fish out a new tool with my left.  Another analogy is the car dash board, glancing at given locations for given tools. Imagine having to tab thru your car dashboard to find the gas gauge.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. one can also file a feature request with the apple developer site. That might be a better way instead of hack that will not probably work with update of Xcode.

Comment: Hashmat, exactly what I did but also hoping for a hold over solution.